# How to manage bears for Brewmaster?

Tags: dota-2

With Brewmaster, earth bear is the important guy when you recombine, you end up at earth. Is there any easy way to select it, send it towards base then select the other two to go attack / distract or whatever?

<kbd>Tab</kbd> works well to cycle between them, but they are all still locked together, I want to quickly send one away then still control the other two.

<kbd>F1</kbd> says *"Select All other unit!"* but, if you select earth bear and send it on his way, then use <kbd>F1</kbd>, it reselects all the bears ( as I guess they are all not Brew)

I can use control groups, but seems like you have to at least waste one ulti to set it up.

Comment: Don't send the Earth brewling back, that's such a waste

Comment: Not everytime, I find I want to do that in the "uh oh, my teammates are all dead I need to get out of here"

Comment: That is not worth the cooldown. Brewmaster with no ult might as well be dead in a teamfight

Answer (score 3):

What I really do for Brew and most micro heroes is set control groups (1,2,3,4)
1 is for the all spirits, 2-4 are for each spirit.
As the fire spirit has no active spell, I usually set him to 4.

If you want to learn more about setting control groups for different heroes and micro-managing in dota 2 you can check this guide http://kyubashi.com/how-to-micro-manage/

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this myself as I suddenly realized something I didn't know before.  Control groups persist across games.  So while demoing the hero I can set up the control groups for the bears and use them in game. 1 group for earth 1 group for the other two.  And f1 will select them all and tab will cycle through them.

However, it still would be nice to know if there is a way to do this on the "fly" easily without control groups.

Comment: nope - control groups are the only reliable way to select a specific unit other than clicking on them - gj figuring it out for yourself though,

Answer (score 0):

Simply hitting the "Tab" key will allow you to cycle through your controllable units.

***This will work with all characters.***

In this situation, when you want one specific unit to move separately than the rest, it's better for you to have only one specific unit selected. It doesn't necessarily need to be one of your own.

If you have all of your units selected, the Tab key will cycle through the different unit types which will allow you to cast whichever unit's unique spells, but movement commands will spread to each of the units currently selected.

If you have a single unit selected (any unit will do - *even one that you don't control*), the Tab key will cycle through the different unit types that you control, but will select each of your controllable unit-types separately and have the ability to send separate movement commands.

For example:

> As Brewmaster, activate your ultimate. Likely, at this point all three of your ultimate characters will be directly selected.
>
> Select one of them (Wind for instance), hit Tab and Fire will selected. Tab again to select Earth. Execute a move command to move Earth elsewhere.
>
> Click-Drag to select Wind and Fire, then the Tab key will only toggle those two different units and send the same move/attack commands to those two units only.

Comment: The "Tab" key is the default key. It is possible to rebind this functionality, in which case these instructions would be less effective